# How to add cooldown between messages for discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The following code works fine, but I want to add a wait time so that the code will only work once for a set period of time then reset.

For example, if someone messages "hello", I want the bot to reply. However, if someone messages "hello" 20 seconds later, I want the bot to ignore the message and any other "hello" messages for a given time (say 2 minutes).

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if bot.user == message.author:
   return

  if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in hello_message):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(hello_response))
```

Comment: Store a variable with the timestamp of the last time you triggered this, and check if the last one has been more than 2 minutes ago

Comment: if you would have used commands it easy because you can put a time from one command to another here you need to listen to the person above me and just use datetime or anything with time stamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a cooldown decorator. Should look something like this:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 120, commands.BucketType.guild)# the 120 is just 2 minutes, like you said.
```

That should work just fine.